# How to show sum 0 where there are no entries with certain values?

Tags: sql

I need to select weekly report (income for every week per every task type). For some weeks for which there is no entries with some task type I want to print 0 as income, but those groups don't show up in my select. #weeks is temp table which contains all weeks I want to have report for. What should I modify in my query?

```
SELECT weeks.BeginDate, weeks.EndDate, task.TaskId, task.Abbreviation, task.Name, COALESCE(SUM([entry.Income]), 0) AS IncomePerWeek 
FROM Task task 
LEFT JOIN Entry entry
ON task.TaskId = entry.TaskId 
INNER JOIN #weeks weeks 
ON entry.EntryDate BETWEEN weeks.BeginDate 
AND weeks.EndDate
GROUP BY weeks.BeginDate, weeks.EndDate, task.TaskId, task.Abbreviation, task.Name
ORDER BY weeks.BeginDate, task.Abbreviation
```

So I want result to look like this:

```
BeginDate    EndDate    TaskId    Abbreviation    Name    IncomePerWeek
----------------------------------------------------------------------
09/11/2015   15/11/2015  1        FT              First   15
09/11/2015   15/11/2015  2        ST              Second  0
...
```

So, in week 09/11/2015 - 15/11/2015 there was no any entry in table Entry with TaskId 2, but still I want to get row for that week and task with IncomePerWeek = 0.

Comment: Do another LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN?

Comment: Difference is that now we get one row for every week (which has at least one missing TaskId) like this:
09/11/2015   15/11/2015  NULL        NULL              NULL   NULL,
but I want to get cross join of weeks and tasks with sum 0 where there is no any entry for the week and the task.

Comment: Not sure If I understand: You want to see for each week all the tasks? Each of them with the sum of the entries or 0 if no entry exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works:

```
SELECT WT.BeginDate, WT.EndDate, WT.TaskId, WT.Abbreviation, WT.Name, SUM(COALESCE(entries.Income, 0)) AS IncomePerWeek 
    FROM Entry AS entries 
        RIGHT JOIN (
            SELECT weeks.BeginDate, weeks.EndDate, tasks.TaskId, tasks.Abbreviation, tasks.Name
                FROM Task AS tasks, #weeks AS weeks                     
        ) AS WT ON (entries.EntryDate BETWEEN WT.BeginDate AND WT.EndDate) AND WT.TaskId = entries.TaskId 
    GROUP BY WT.BeginDate, WT.EndDate, WT.TaskId, WT.Abbreviation, WT.Name
    ORDER BY WT.BeginDate, WT.Abbreviation
```

The '*main point*' is to create as many *entries* as cardinality of *weeks* * *tasks* (`WT` subquery cartesian product and 
`RIGHT JOIN` with `entries`).

Then the non-existence of entries is treated correctly for the `IncomePerWeek` calulation by mean of `COALESCE` on `NULL` values.

Comment: Result is just the same as result from my query.

Comment: @bamby i totally rewrote

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to use `SUM(COALESCE([entry.Income], 0)) AS IncomePerWeek`.

However, your FROM clause is ambiguous to me.  You've got a LEFT JOIN and then immediately follow that with an INNER JOIN to an OUTER table.  That's making everything implicit INNER JOIN.

Depending on your data, I'd use either this:

```
FROM Task task 
LEFT JOIN Entry entry
ON task.TaskId = entry.TaskId 
LEFT JOIN #weeks weeks 
ON entry.EntryDate BETWEEN weeks.BeginDate 
AND weeks.EndDate
```

Or this:

```
FROM Task task 
LEFT JOIN (Entry entry
    INNER JOIN #weeks weeks 
    ON entry.EntryDate BETWEEN weeks.BeginDate 
    AND weeks.EndDate)
ON task.TaskId = entry.TaskId
```

Which you should use depends on the exact relationship between `#weeks` and `entry`.  If you've got entries that don't have any weeks and you want those included, then the first one is good.  If you don't want any entries that don't have any weeks (or entries not having weeks should be impossible) then the second is good.

Comment: @bambi You're going to have to be more descriptive than that.

Comment: @bambi Are you trying to say you want your results to have records from `#weeks` even when there's no data at all in the `entry` table?  How is that supposed to work?  `#weeks` is only related to `task` by the `entry` table.  Unless you just want a giant Cartesian product, what results are you expecting?